# How to Import .py file with third-party package(like numpy) from C?

Tags: python, numpy, python-import, python-c-api

I'm using visual studio to import a python file from a c/c++ file to use a function(named lalala) defined in PythonApplication7.py. I'm trying to use Python-C-API to do this.
The C file is:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    PyObject* pModule, * pFunc;
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    int result;

    Py_Initialize();
    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("PythonApplication8");//here, import a python file without 3rd party package
    if (!pModule) {
        PyErr_Print(); //print error
    }

    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "func1");
    if (!pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        PyErr_Print();
        Py_XDECREF(pModule); 
    }

    PyObject* pValue1 = Py_BuildValue("i", a);
    PyObject* pValue2 = Py_BuildValue("i", b);

    if (!pValue1 || !pValue2) {
        Py_XDECREF(pValue1);
        Py_XDECREF(pValue2);
    }

    PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue2);

    PyObject* pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    PyArg_Parse(pValue, "i", &result);

    printf("The result is: %d\n", result);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;

}
```

the PythonApplication8.py file(in same directory):

```
import PythonApplication7 as p

def func1(a,b):
    return p.lalala(a,b)
```

the PythonApplication7.py file is:

```
import math
import numpy
def lalala(a,b):
    return a+b

c=math.sqrt(1)
```

Without third-party package(numpy here) imported, I can pass arguments from C to python and receive the output of function in python to C. However, after I import numpy there is an error message: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'" and other related errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py", line 24, in 
> from . import multiarray
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 10, in 
> from . import overrides
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 8, in 
> from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'**

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line 158, in 
> from numpy.**config** import show as show_config
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy_*config*_.py", line 4, in 
> from numpy.core.*multiarray_umath import (
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_*init**.py", line 50, in 
> raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError:

> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

> **Importing the numpy C-extensions failed.** This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.

> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> Please note and check the following:

> The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\Project7.exe"
> The NumPy version is: "1.26.2"

> and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
> Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

> Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

> **The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\PythonApplication8.py", line 1, in 
> import PythonApplication7 as p
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\PythonApplication7.py", line 2, in 
> import numpy
> File "C:\Users\hyi\source\repos\Project7\x64\Release\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line 163, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) from e
> ImportError: Error importing numpy: **you should not try to import numpy from
> its source directory**; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
> your python interpreter from there.

I have put the liberates containing numpy(python/DLLs,python/Lib) to the same directory of the compiled C's exe file and the python version is 3.9. I have set the include path and library path of the C project in VS to the corresponding path of Python.

There's no problem importing numpy directly in python. I've read the https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html but don't find a solution. Other methods implementing 3rd-party packages from c file is also welcomed.

Update at 12/24:I put python39_d.dll in the additional dependencies in the linker(in vidual studio).The problem disappears after I remove the debug symbol (python39_d.dll). Other Linker settings are as default.

Comment: How are you linking this? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562708/numpy-import-fails-when-embedding-python-in-c) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360372/cant-import-numpy-from-c), this can be caused by removing symbols at the link stage.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks. I put python39_d.dll in the additional dependencies in the linker. The problem disappears after I remove the debug symbol (python39_d.dll).  And I'm now finding ways to use the debug symbol.

Comment: So the problem was you linking to the debug version of *Python* library? What do you want to debug? For that to work you'd need a *Numpy* version that links to that lib (or build one yourself). Try debugging your code with a dummy module.